# Unable to access S3bucket in Frankfurt region

Tags: amazon-s3

I created a S3bucket in Frankfurt region then I checked the properties of that bucket it shows the owner id as randomly generated numbers eg.3564331321235643. I am not able to access the bucket in Frankfurt region.

Previously I worked in a bucket which was created in Oregon region and I checked the properties of that bucket which shows owner id with a valid name like eg.raj. I can able to access the bucket in Frankfurt region. Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not able to access the bucket in Frankfurt region"? If you can see the properties of the bucket, then you *can* access the bucket. Do you mean that you cannot access objects *within* the bucket? How are you attempting to access them, and what error are you experiencing. Please provide more information (eg what you did, what happened, what errors) and we will be better able to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your time, John. I can able to access the bucket in aws.amazon.com. Through MapReduce code , I try to access the bucket which was created in Frankfurt region at that time I'm not able to access the bucket. But I can able to access the oregon region bucket through mapreduce code.

Comment: In which region is your EMR cluster running? Is it in the same region where the bucket that works (Oregon)? What does your "Permissions" section look like on the two buckets -- can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: John, Before creating a EMR cluster. I ran a code in Eclipse(IDE), through mapreduce i'm trying to access the bucket in frankfurt region but I'm not able to access. I created two buckets in Oregon as well as in Ireland region, I can able to access those regions. But I've problem only with frankfurt region. I came to know about Signature version 4 issue. Is that was a issue?

Comment: Yes, if it works in every region except Frankfurt, then this may be the issue. The differences with Frankfurt are Sig 4 only, and a slightly differently-formatted endpoint URL (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region). Also, a vague chance that software you are using is out-of-date and hasn't been updated at all for the Frankfurt region.

Comment: Yes, it was an issue with SIG 4 only. Now, I can able to access the Frankfurt region bucket